# click on an image to load another image in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an image displaying using the jquery. When mouse over to that image, I like the mouse to change to be clickable and when clicked, I like to load another image. This is my code and not working. Any ideas?

html code:

jquery code:

```
$("#div1").click(function () {
    var img_cpu = "http://192.168.101.1/cpu.png";
    var myImage = new Image();
    $(myImage).load(function () {
        $("#div2").html(myImage)    
    }).error(function () {
        $('#div2').hide();
    })
    .attr('src', img_cpu)
});
```

Comment: a jsFiddle or a bit of your HTML source code would be probably helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some issues occurred

- <del>you created a new image `var myImage = new Image();`  but you didn't specified a `src` later (so load event never triggers)</del>
- `myImage32` is not defined anywhere in your code

furthermore be sure that `cpu.png`

- is inside the same folder
- has minimum permission (`644`) to be viewed
- is not already cached, otherwise load event could never occur: in this case you should check for `complete` property and trigger the handler defined for load event (see snippet below)

---

```
 $(myImage).one('load', function () {   /* use one() */
     $("#div2").html(myImage32)    
 })
 .attr('src', img_cpu);

 if (!!myImage.complete) $(myImage).trigger('load');
```

Comment: I had a typo on the original code. I corrected it. I am binding a click event to div and trying to load an image. It should work but not. I dont now what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat, it looks like you're forgetting to put the URL of the image in your load function. It should look something like `.load('url/to/image/', function() ...`